# SQL Server 2008 r2 can't login

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection, connection-string

I am working on Windows Server 2003 using SQL Server 2008 R2 and the .NET Framework 4.

#### My problem

I can't login to my database from my website **although I can login from my Management Studio**

I created a login named `William`.

My connection string is

```
<add name="TestDbConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=RESv5;User Id=William;Password=MYPASSWORD;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I got this error:

> Login failed for user 'William'

#### NOTE:

The same username and password I use in the Management Studio and I can login.

Comment: Yakshemash. This look like security issue. Please search google for "web access to sql server". First link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht43wsex(v=vs.100).aspx .I hope it help. Chenqui.

Comment: Did you also create a **user** for that login `William` in your `RESv5` database?

Comment: @marc_s I have just solved my problem, it was the connection string wrong, I should have used the name of the server/the name of the database. This helps me

Answer (score 0):

Are the website, the SQL Server instance, and SSMS all running on your local machine?

If they are not the same machine, then that is probably the source of the problem:  "(local)" on a different machine will mean something different than "(local)" on your own personal laptop.

Try this for the Data Source portion of the name:

```
Data Source=LocalServerName
```

... where `LocalServerName` is the name of the server on which the SQL Server instance is running.  If the database is on your machine and the website is elsewhere, use the name of your machine for `LocalServerName`.

ETA:  If you have more than one SQL Server instance running and the one you want is NOT named MSSQLSERVER, you would reference it like this:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS
```

As `marc_s` points out, if the instance is called MSSQLSERVER, you can use `(local)` as you are doing, or

```
Data Source=.
```

Comment: They are in the same machine, but that machine has sql server 2008 and sql server 2005

Comment: The `MSSQLSERVER` instance is the **default** instance which you refer to **without** specifying an instance name, e.g. in this case, you should use `Data Source=.` (or `Data Source=(local)`) and not use what you're mentioning here...

Comment: @marc_s please help me, nothing works for me until now